# Database Migration failed from SQL Server 2012 to 2016

Tags: sql-server

After restoring backup of SQL Server 2012 to 2016 at the 100% completion it has failed and taken the database to recovery pending.

Able to do restore withe same backup of SQL Server 2012 to 2014 its successful and then tried to do from 2104 to 2016 but same error.

```
Error: 928, Severity: 20, State: 1.
During upgrade, database raised exception 211, severity 23, state 109, address 00007FFA50AB1225. Use the exception number to determine the cause.
Error: 211, Severity: 23, State: 109.
Corruption in database ID 7, object ID 3 possibly due to schema or catalog inconsistency.
```

Have done integrity check and catalog check on source.
Also have tried to do repair allow data loss after taking to emergency mode.
Have tried to detach and attach with single file. Even tried with rebuild log.
Got the same resources as of source server.

Comment: Did DBCC CHECKCATALOG on source report any error?

Comment: @krish, did you check about this [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/4019701/fix-database-schema-is-corrupted-when-you-restore-a-database-from-a-sn) as make sure you have installed at least SP1

Comment: No error on source when running CHECKDB? Even with EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS ?

Comment: No, haven't seen any errors on CHECKCATALOG and even on CHECKDB. it is currently on SP2

Comment: Is the database TDE enabled? Are you using compression? See [this bugfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4101502/tde-enabled-database-backup-with-compression-causes-corruption) in SP2 CU1/CU2